# Android app transfer with Play App Signing

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I've had to transfer an app to a different account before and it was pretty straightforward, you just keep signing it with the same key as before.

But if I was to enroll my apps into Google Play App Signing, would I have to give to the another account owner the upload key? Is he supposed to just generate a new one and register it with Google? Would anything need to be done with the publish key, or would it be handled entirely by Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having your app enrolled in Google Play App Signing does not make a difference in the transfer of apps.

The app uploaded to the Play Console will still need to be uploaded with the upload key, so yes you will need to transfer the upload key to the new app owner. The new app owner can then decide to reset the key if they wish to (See ["Create a new upload key"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)).

Nothing needs to be done with the release key (also called "deployment key"): it is associated with the app and not the account, so Google will keep signing it correctly.